# How to provide DISTINCT functionality in WCF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, distinct, wcf-data-services

I have WCF Data service on top of EF (old-fashioned edmx; not code-first) that has millions of rows of data. I am restricting result set to 500 rows. So far, so good!

I want to give the consumer the ability to "drill" into the data. Ideally, consumer code would run something like `select distinct Province from` my service, user would choose the state, and then code would run `select distinct Zip where Province == p` (my business domain is very different, but hopefully you get the picture!).

Obviously, I can't get everything and run distinct on the client side. How do I provide this ability in the service? I don't have EntitySet "Provinces" or "Zips" exposed in the service. Should I extend MyEntities class, and try to simulate those sets there? Or is there a simpler way to expose other collections, besides the ones that are automatically exposed from Entity Framework?

I hope the question makes sense...

UPDATE: I think I caused the confusion when I mentioned that I was using WCF service. I actually am using WCF *Data* Service trying to provide OData wrapper over Entity Framework 4.1. Hopefully, this clarifies the question...

Comment: Why would you ever need to urun a DISCTINCT here? Crappy databbase design? Make us understand the issue more, but thigns like Procinve, Zip will likely eat your server performance wise when you run them a lot of times with a distinct.

Comment: On the back end it's not even relational database but statistical sampling. So, on the server side select distinct is very fast (if I understand SAS internals correctly, it's partitioned on "Province" and indexed on "Zip" within partition). So, I expect performance to be satisfactory. Regardless - the users need to see what Provinces/Zips are available and get results within Zip - so my first question is functionality, not performance.

Comment: If perforamnce starts stinking, you always can cache ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered dropping your supposedly propietary interafce and going standards?

It is quit easy to expose ODATA from .NET and that allows the user to drill down. THen all you need are some transformations to expose elements like Province or Zip as in a sane data model and there you go ;)

The good thing about OData is that it allows you to easily pass LINQ to the backend and do projections (get me all proovinces from customers where customer name starts with "a") and doesn ot necessarily deal with compelte entities.

Comment: Maybe we have some misunderstanding, but how is what I am doing *not* ODATA and *not* standards? All examples of OData that I saw (and followed) say "create new item - WCF Data Services". What is proprietary here? You say "it is quit[e] easy to expose ODATA from .NET and that allows the user to drill down". That's exactly what I am trying to do! Can you point to an example of that?

Comment: Example of OData being exposed as WCF Data Service (one of many): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/video/gg601462